# Left to right swipe not enabling edit mode - iOS7 bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have supported both iOS6 & iOS7 in my app. But the issue is only happening in iOS7. If I am swiping right to left then I'm getting swipe to delete button properly.

But If I swipe left to right then tableview didSelect delegate method getting called instead of swipe to delete option.

Any solution for this bug ?

Comment: isn't this the correct behavior? iOS 7 removed the left-to-right swipe in table views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by overriding swipe gesture.

But I'll remain open for new answer and suggestions.